# Vacation visa to Jamaica for Nigerian citizens

Tags: visas, nigerian-citizens, jamaica

I would like to know the requirements to get a vacation visa from Nigeria to Jamaica. I've never applied before and have only been to Ghana, & Cotonou.

Comment: Call the Jamaican embassy in Nigeria TELEPHONE; (+234) 9 291 3490 (+234) 81 3606 3356; FAX; EMAIL; jamaicanembassy@yahoo.com ...By the way there are no countries called Gahana and cutonu

Comment: Did you mean Ghana and Benin (Cotonou)? You could [start with the web site](http://jhcnigeria.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=71&Itemid=108) for Jamaica's High Commission in Abuja. It explains what is needed to visit the country.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.